# How to set keys in mongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

The idea is to go from a collection of documents like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("58ff4fa372ac97344d5672c2"), 
    "direction" : 1,
    "post" : ObjectId("58ff4ea572ac97344d5672c1"), 
    "user" : ObjectId("586b84239ae9590ab66bd3ad")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("58ff4c9f2952d7341d4afc0c"), 
    "direction" : -1, 
    "post" : ObjectId("58fc15a3fb3bed0fd54bfd95"), 
    "user" : ObjectId("586b84239ae9590ab66bd3ad")
}
```

To this:

```
[
    //post: direction
    "58ff4ea572ac97344d5672c1": 1,
    "58fc15a3fb3bed0fd54bfd95": -1
]
```

I can't seem to find anything in the MongoDB Aggregation docs that allows you to set the key name using the value of another field.

I'm expecting this code to work, but I can see why it doesn't. It thinks that "$post" refers to a MongoDB expression.

```
db.votes.aggregate([
    {$group: {
        _id: null,
        entries: {
            $addToSet: {
                "$post": "$direction"
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Comment: MongoDB 3.4 Has `$objectToArray` and `$arrayToObject` which can effectively be used to make the "values" into "keys". However it is not possible to "cast" non-string values into a string based key. And string based keys are a BSON constraint. The only thing that "stringifies" here is the client code. I suggest that is where you actually do it, since you are not actually asking to "aggregate" anything.

Comment: So in fact all you need do for your result is `db.votes.find().map(d => ({ [d.post]: d.direction }) )`